# Hermite polynomials form complete system

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

> Let $h_0(x)=e^{-x^2/2}$ and $h_k=B^kh_0$, where $B=-\dfrac{d}{dx}+x$. Show that the $\dfrac{h_k}{\|h_k\|_2}$'s form a complete orthogonal system.
>
> We can show that $h_k(x)=H_k(x)e^{-x^2/2}$, where $H_k(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $k$ defined by $H_k(x)=2xH_{k-1}(x)-H'_{k-1}(x)$.

(Hint: We have $\langle Af,g\rangle=\langle f,Bg\rangle$, where $A=\dfrac{d}{dx}+x$. Consider $\langle B^kh_0,B^lh_0\rangle$, and use the commutator formula $[A,B^n]=ncB^{n-1}$.)

We can derive that $\langle B^kh_0,B^lh_0\rangle=\langle A^lB^kh_0,h_0\rangle$. However,  I don't see why this should be equal to $0$. Also, what does the commutator formula mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think using the commutator formula is the best way. In my opinion it is easier to just note how $A$ works on functions of the form $f\cdot h_0$:

$$\begin{align}
A\left(f(x)e^{-x^2/2}\right) &= \frac{d}{dx}\left(f(x)e^{-x^2/2}\right) + xf(x)e^{-x^2/2}\\
&= f'(x)e^{-x^2/2} + f(x)\left(-xe^{-x^2/2}\right) + xf(x)e^{-x^2/2}\\
&= f'(x)e^{-x^2/2}.
\end{align}$$

Then, for $k < m$, you have

$$\langle h_k, h_m\rangle = \langle A^mh_k,h_0\rangle = \langle A^m(H_kh_0),h_0\rangle$$

and the above finishes it in no time.

If you use the commutator formula, you get - as a first step -

$$\langle B^kh_0,B^mh_0\rangle = \langle AB^k h_0,B^{m-1}h_0\rangle = \langle (kcB^{k-1} + B^kA)h_0,B^{m-1}h_0\rangle,$$

and you still need to use $Ah_0 = 0$ to simplify it.

To see the completeness of the system, we show that the orthogonal complement of its span is $\{0\}$.

Let $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Consider the function $F \colon \mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ defined by

$$F(z) = \int_\mathbb{R} f(x) e^{zx - x^2/2}\,dx.$$

Since $\left\lvert e^{zx-x^2/2}\right\rvert \leqslant e^{\lvert z\rvert\cdot\lvert x\rvert-x^2/2}$, the exponential factor is in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$, uniformly dominated for $z$ in any compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$, hence continuous, and by your favourite method (Morera's theorem, dominated convergence theorem, …), you can show that $F$ is holomorphic.

Now suppose $\langle h_k,f\rangle = 0$ for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$. Since each monomial $x^m$ is a linear combination of $H_0,\dotsc,H_m$, we then have

$$\begin{align}
F^{(m)}(0) &= \int_\mathbb{R} f(x) \left(\frac{d}{dz}\right)^m\Biggl\lvert_{z=0}e^{zx-x^2/2}\,dx\\
&= \int_\mathbb{R} f(x)\cdot x^me^{-x^2/2}\,dx\\
&= \langle x^m\cdot h_0,f\rangle\\
&= 0.
\end{align}$$

Thus we have $F \equiv 0$. But

$$\begin{align}
F(-it) &= \int_\mathbb{R} f(x) e^{-itx-x^2/2}\,dx\\
&= \int_\mathbb{R} \left(f(x)e^{-x^2/2}\right)e^{-itx}\,dx\\
&= N\cdot \mathcal{F}\left[f\cdot h_0\right](t),
\end{align}$$

is, modulo a normalisation factor, the Fourier transform of $f\cdot h_0$. So $\mathcal{F}\left[ f\cdot h_0\right] = 0$, whence $f\cdot h_0 = 0$ almost everywhere. Since $h_0 > 0$ everywhere, that means $f = 0$ almost everywhere, and therefore

$$\operatorname{span} \left\lbrace h_k : k \in \mathbb{N}\right\rbrace^\perp = \{0\}.$$

Comment: Nice, Daniel! Still, how do you prove it forms a *complete* orthogonal system?

Comment: Complex analysis, and Fourier transformation.

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance, but I'm not familiar with Morera's theorem, and I don't know how to use dominated convergence theorem to show holomorphicity. Could you perhaps give just a rough idea of a proof (using either theorem that you feel yields a better/shorter proof)?

Comment: Just use the DCT to see that you can differentiate partially with respect to the real and to the imaginary part of $z$. The Cauchy-Riemann equations hold for the integral because they hold for the integrand.

Comment: I see. And to check that the Cauchy-Riemann equations hold for the integrand, I write $z=a+ib$ and differentiate with respect to $a$ and $b$, right?

Comment: If you can't yet say that it is obvious that the integrand is holomorphic, then yes, you differentiate wrt $a$ resp. $b$ and check the CR equations. But that $z \mapsto e^{\alpha z}$ is holomorphic for any fixed $\alpha$ should not need further elaboration if you can legitimately use the word holomorphic at all. (And thus, it would then be sufficient to note that differentiation under the integral is legitimate without actually computing the partial derivatives.)